# thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop, subcode=0x0) using search

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, exc-bad-instruction

I'm trying to use a search function in a table view. the data changes like it supposed to but the moment I hit a cell that has been generated after the search it won't take me to the next view. It crashes on this piece of code on the selectedIndex var.

```
if self.tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
        var selectedIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
        selectedTimeSlot = filteredTimeSlots[selectedIndex]
    } else {
        var selectedIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
        selectedTimeSlot = timeSlots[selectedIndex]
    }
```

this is my entire code

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ClockEditTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {

    // Contains all time slots
    var timeSlots: [TimeSlot] = [TimeSlot]()

    // Contains the search results
    var filteredTimeSlots: [TimeSlot] = [TimeSlot]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

//        timeSlots = DataHelper.getTimeSlots()
        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://wouterhabets.com/acts.json")
            .response { (request, response, data, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    self.timeSlots = DataHelper.getTimeSlots(data as NSData)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                } else {
                    self.timeSlots = DataHelper.getTimeSlots()
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
        }

        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var actDetailViewController: ActDetailsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ActDetailsViewController
        var selectedTimeSlot: TimeSlot

        if self.tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            var selectedIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
            selectedTimeSlot = filteredTimeSlots[selectedIndex]
        } else {
            var selectedIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
            selectedTimeSlot = timeSlots[selectedIndex]
        }

        actDetailViewController.timeSlot = selectedTimeSlot
    }

    // Return the amount of cells to display
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var count: Int

        // Check if the user is searching
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            count = filteredTimeSlots.count
        } else {
            count = timeSlots.count
        }

        return count
    }

    // Fill cells with data
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("actCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        var timeSlot: TimeSlot

        // Check if the user is searching
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            timeSlot = filteredTimeSlots[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            timeSlot = timeSlots[indexPath.row]
        }

        cell.textLabel?.text = timeSlot.act?.title

        return cell
    }

    func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
        self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString)
        return true
    }

    func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchScope searchOption: Int) -> Bool {
        self.filterContentForSearchText(self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.text)
        return true
    }

    func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
        self.filteredTimeSlots = self.timeSlots.filter({( timeSlot: TimeSlot) -> Bool in

            // Optional scope search code
            // let categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (band.category == scope)
            let searchText = searchText.lowercaseString

            let stringMatch = timeSlot.act?.title?.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText)
            return (stringMatch != nil) // && categoryMatch
        })
    }

}
```

Does anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong and what I should do to fix this

Answer (score 0):

`self.tableView` is the main table view, so

`self.tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView`

will never be true

You should check if the active tableView is the main tableView or the search tableView

```
if self.searchDisplayController.active {
    // get the index path from search table ... 
} else {
    // get the index path from main table ...
}
```

That was answered here too.
[searchDisplayController, UITableView, Core Data and Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24489926/searchdisplaycontroller-uitableview-core-data-and-swift)

Also, be careful when using the exlamation in

```
self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
```

since that could return nil, and if it returns nil you will get a runtime error